# Trying to display the value of a column in a clusplot chart using R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, powerbi

I am working with R in Power Bi and show a Clusplot Chart - that is working fine.

But how can i display column1 as the label in the clusters, instead of the numbers (1-27).

[image]

This is my code:

```
library(cluster)
D=daisy(dataset, metric='gower')
H.fit <- hclust(D, method="ward")
plot(H.fit)
groups <- cutree(H.fit, k=5, tree) # cut tree into 4 clusters
rect.hclust(H.fit, k=3, border="red") 
clusplot(dataset, groups, color=TRUE, shade=TRUE, lines=0, main= 'Customer segments', span=F, labels=2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `row.names`.

If your rows do not have names, they will be using row numbers.

Comment: great - its working with following command: row.names(dataset) <- dataset$Column1